# SQL cross referencing another table to check data

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

student table --> [image: This is student table]

grades table --> [image: This is grades table]

What I am trying to do is get the first name and last name of the student who is eligible to take a class who has a grade equal or greater than a 'C' in a course.

How can I achieve this using a sql query?
So far, all I have is:
`SELECT firstname, lastname, tnumber FROM students`

I am unsure how to check if the student's grade in a courseid.

Thanks.

Example table inside of grades:

[image]

Comment: Do some research regarding `JOIN`. You can connect two tables on a shared column by doing something like `... FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you need is:

```
SELECT students.firstname, students.lastname, students.tnumber, grades.tnumber FROM students, grades WHERE grades.tnumber=students.tnumber AND (grades.Grade='A' OR grades.Grade='B' OR grades.Grade='C')
```