# SQL keeping count of how many times

Tags: mysql

I have a table of grades/courses. I am trying to see how many times a person has taken a course, and also return the highest grade they have achieved.

So far I have:
`SELECT tnumber, courseid, grade FROM grades`

I need to display all tnumbers that have taken the same course more than once.  Also list the students highest grade for the course.

How do you keep count of how many times a course has occurred?
I want to display the student's tnumber, course_id, attempts, and highest grade. And all within a single query.

If I need to show an example of my table/s. Let me know and Ill post them. I just don't want to overload the page with code!

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Learn what is basically "basic" sql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max

Comment: use the aggregate  function `count(*)` but you have to add a group by clause the tnumber (assuming that's the student) and you'd need to select the max(grade) assuming numeric or min(grade) if alphabetic.

Comment: Is Grade Numeric or Alphabetic?  Max on a Number will give you the highest.  Max on a string will give you F when you probably want to show B.

Comment: Grade is alphabetic, so using MIN(grade) will be the best option. Here is my current query: `SELECT tnumber, courseid, MIN(grades.grade), COUNT(*) FROM grades GROUP BY tnumber`

Comment: I would recommend only spelling out table names when you have more than 1 table in the query and even then, using aliases would be wise; instead of spelling out table names.  It makes the code easier to read in the long run.  **you needed to add courseID to the group by**. you want the unique count for each student AND course, not just student.  mySQL extends the group by clause so no error is thrown when you have a selected value using aggregration but not in the group by, generally this will not give you the desired results however as the engine is free to choose any course for the student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example (table alias G not necessary as only 1 table is involved using for example only)

```
SELECT g.tnumber, g.courseid, min(g.grade), count(*)
FROM grades g
GROUP BY g.tNumber, g.CourseID
```

This returns the tnumber and courseID for each record with the highest (alphabetic grade) and a count of how many records exist for that same tnumber and courseID.  You could use count(*) or count(1).

Based on a prior [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40247145/sql-cross-referencing-another-table-to-check-data) I'm assuming grade is alphabetic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query (I assume grade is a number column):

```
select tnumber, course_id, count(course_id), max(grade)
from grades
group by tnumber, course_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tnumber, courseid, COUNT(courseid) times_taken, MAX(grade) highest_grade FROM grades GROUP BY tnumber, courseid
```

This assumes that `grade` is a number.